# why doesn't append function of TextView work in android studio in kotlin in customView

Tags: kotlin, textview, append

I was making a custom view to learn android studio. In the meantime, to check if my code work correctly, I write the following code. I expected

```
4layout_width=wrap_content
layout_height=wrap_content
id=@+id/customView
```

is written in textView but still 4 is been writing. what went wrong? is this android studio's error? To make correct code, how can I do?
custom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.myapplication.MyView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.root_layout)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, layout, true)
    }
}
class MyView : View {
    constructor(context : Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context : Context, attr : AttributeSet?) : super(context, attr){
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val layout = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)
        val textView = layout!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        if(attr != null){
            for(i in 0 until attr.attributeCount){
                val string = "${attr.getAttributeName(i)}=${attr.getAttributeValue(i)}\n"
                textView.append(string)
            }
        }
    }
    constructor(context : Context, attr : AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr : Int) :
            super(context, attr, defStyleAttr)
}
```

Comment: You created your own view, so you need to add it to your layout like any other view. You do not need to give it the id.

Comment: i added it to my layout through this code : inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, layout, true)